# Accessing pointers after erasing from Map

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, access-violation

The sample scenario in my code implementation is as follows

I have a map defined as `map<int,map<int,object*>*>` . The inner map which is in heap has a object pointer.

The scenario is,

After using(processing) all the elements in the inner map. I will erase the inner map contents using iterator. But the object* will not be deleted. I will use the object pointer further after erasing the key from the map.

My question is will that object* exist even after erasing it's presence in the map. As far as my understanding , yes the object is in heap and it can be used even after the erase in map. But i am facing random crash in the process after few minutes of execution. This makes me to post the question here.

```
multimap<ULONG, Class*>::iterator it_top3 = InnerMap->begin();
if (InnerMap->size() >= classLimit)
{
    if (it_top3->first <= ClassObj->m_classSize)
    {
        if (it_top3->second != NULL)
        {
            delete it_top3->second;
            it_top3->second = NULL;
        }
        InnerMap->erase(it_top3);
        InnerMap->insert(pair<ULONG, Class*>(ClassObj->m_classSize, ClassObj));
}
```

Secondly , On analyzing debug diag the line `it_top3->second = NULL;` points as the crash point with access violation exception. What would be possible reason for the crash here.?

Comment: If you have a container of pointers, removing an element from the container will not invalidate the pointer or the object being pointed to. All it does is remove the element from the container.

Comment: It might be worth to use an std::unique_ptr or a boost::shared_ptr insteed of a standard pointer.

Answer (score 4):

You don't just erase from map, the line

```
        delete it_top3->second;
        it_top3->second = NULL;
```

deallocates the pointer, which may cause your crashes.

Just the `InnerMap->erase()` call would do what you'd expect.

Comment: I'd +1 if you promoted C++'s `nullptr` ;)

Comment: from ur answer , my first question got cleared that even after map erase the object exists. But the second question is why there is a crash in the place i have specified in the sample code. What would be the reason.?

Comment: first: no point in promoting `nullptr` in a row I suggest to remove.

Comment: Now, in reply to Sel_va: This is really hard to tell. But I can tell you, if something crashes with an access violation as you mentioned, it hardly ever is in the place where the error in your code is. In most cases, you did something wrong elsewhere and ran into undefined behaviour.